# jQuery Mobile & Backbone.js dynamic image loading issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone and jQuery Mobile to develop a fairly basic application. I have a basic settings page and on the page, different settings are denoted by different images. If the setting is on, the image source is set to one image, and if it is off it is set to another, dynamically of course.

So for example,

```
<a href="#" class="autoupdateBtn"><img src="images/autoupdate-off.png" style="height:45px;" id="autoupdate" /></a>
```

Now I'm listening for the link to be clicked to change the icon source, which works fine to start with. I'm using Phonegap's localStorage to store the individual settings. So when the page renders, I call:

```
var d = new Date();
var autoupdate = window.localStorage.getItem('autoupdate');
$('#autoupdate').attr("src", "images/autoupdate-"+autoupdate+".png?"+d.getTime());
```

Now that works fine the first time you load up the page, but bizzarely, doesn't after that. If I try revisiting the page, it will just load up the default image in the source. However what's even more bizzare is that if you go into the console and type in:

```
$('#autoupdate').attr('src');
```

It gives you the correct source! So the attribute itself has been changed but the image itself doesn't! I've tried using things like .trigger('create') and all that, but no luck at all - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the Date() in a variable, use it as `new Date()` directly in the code. Try the below:

```
$('#autoupdate').attr("src", "images/autoupdate-"+autoupdate+".png?" + (new Date()).getTime());
```

Comment: Tried that, no luck :/ I even tried just changing a CSS property of the image with no luck and tried using a physical button rather than an image and it still doesn't change on the second viewing...